# Apple LLVM Compiler 4.2 Error exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors

This has been asked a lot of times, but I can't find a solution for my problem. This is the error i get:

> clang: error: no input files
>   Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Screenshot:

[image]

I hope someone can help me. I am using the Parse SDK. (see: parse.com)

Comment: `PopularTagsFree-Prefix.pch` seems to be missing in action.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson , I have this file.

Comment: There seems to be a space in the path "PopularTags Free/PopularTagsFree-Prefix.pch". Remove the space in the path and add the .pch file again in your xcode project.

Comment: @Amar, it doesn't work either.

Comment: You may have the file, but is it part of your Xcode project? Are you sure that it has **exactly** the same name and location as in the build settings? Have you done a git (or other version control) diff to see what the difference is between the version that compiled and the version that does not?

Comment: @Abizern, yes. It has exactly the same name. Do you think the problem can be somewhere else? I'm stuck with this, and don't know what I should do.

Comment: Have you tried removing it from your build settings and then adding it again?

Comment: @Abizern, yes, but nothing happens.

Comment: Please show me images of the following. 1) a screen capture of a terminal screen that shows me that you have the pch file in the location that you say it is in. 2) a screen capture of your Xcode project that shows that the pch file is in the project. 3) a screen capture of your build settings that shows where the compiler is looking for the pch file.

Comment: @Abizern, I didn't understand what you meant with 1), but here you have pictures of 2) and 3). http://bildr.no/view/1615689 http://bildr.no/view/1615691

Comment: Look at the second image. The name is `PopularTags-Prefix.pch` Now look at your error message which is looking for a file named `PopularTagsFree-Prefix.pch` and the name of your file is `PopularTags-Prefix.pch`. It helps if you provide up to date error messages.

Comment: You should check your build settingsGCC_PREFIX_HEADER = DC Wire Sizer/SupportingFiles/DC Wire Sizer-Prefix.pch

//:configuration = Release
GCC_PREFIX_HEADER = DC Wire Sizer/SupportingFiles/DC Wire Sizer-Prefix.pch

//:completeSettings = some
GCC_PREFIX_HEADER

Comment: @Abizern, I have tried everything. It still won't work. Do you think I can share the code on github, and then you guys can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your build settings and verify the file name and path in GCC_PREFIX_HEADER

Apple LLVM compiler 4.2 - language
    Prefix Header

**This is mine. Just an example**

```
GCC_PREFIX_HEADER = DC Wire Sizer/SupportingFiles/DC Wire Sizer-Prefix.pch
```

FYI: If you select the Prefix Header build setting in Xcode and copy you get the line above but when you set the value you shouldn't include 'GCC_PREFIX_HEADER = '

**This is incorrect:**

[image]

[image]

**This is the correct setting:**

[image]
[image]

Note: The values are different then above because they are from a different project.

Comment: I can't get it to work. Where shall I add this? When I add it to the Apple LLVM 4.2 Compiler Language, nothing happens.

Comment: I updated the answer. You need to check what you have set and make sure it matches the file you have. You can't use my value. That is just an example. I can't cut and past from the screen screenshot. The two lines before the error message you copied is the important bits.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. But now I have one error left. Look at this screenshot: http://bildr.no/view/1616207

Comment: Hi @JosteinLiverød I updated the answer to include screenshots so it is clearer. You need to remove 'GCC_PREFIX_HEADER = ' from the value. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

that .pch file should be created when you create your project, must of accidently deleted it somehow, just create a new file with that name and put this in it:

```
#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_5_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 5.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

may need to be slightly different but should get your project working again

Comment: oh, that is strange then. did you just create this project? quickest would be to create a new one and paste whatever code you have done into the new one, if i think of what could be wrong ill let you know

Comment: I have worked on this for a while, so it's a lot of code. And the app is already on the App Store. I tried to implement the Parse SDK, and I removed the other linker flags. Now I can't run the project 'cause of this problem.